# MySQL Schema integrity checking

Tags: mysql

The MySQL schema was uploaded to the server with `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0`

Now I’d like to check the existence of all the foreign tables.
Is there a way to automatically check all the schema on integrity?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation [Create Table Foreign Keys](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

> However, even if foreign_key_checks = 0, MySQL does not permit the
>   creation of a foreign key constraint where a column references a
>   nonmatching column type.

So, if the constraint is there the table and matched columns will be too.

You can get this out of the information_schema.

e.g.

```
SELECT CONCAT(`table_name`, '.', `constraint_name`, ' -> ',
`referenced_table_name`, '.' , `unique_constraint_name`) 'table a.constraint -> table b.key' 
FROM `information_schema`.`referential_constraints`
WHERE `constraint_schema` = 'dbname';
```

Comment: Yes, I know. But this is very cumbersome. I hoped there is a better way than looking through the information_schema.

Comment: Then you need to write some tests. You could look at a testing framework like mytap. My fork of this project on GitHub animalcarpet/mytap has a feature (autotap.sql) that will generate a test script from a 'known good' schema. The coverage includes checks for the existence of all foreign key constraints.